# How to use a custom event listener with a PostSharp aspect

Tags: logging, event-listener, postsharp

I have an `AutoLogExceptionAspect` class, with its partnered event source, `AutoLogExceptionEventSource`, like follows:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class AutoLogExceptionAspect
    Inherits OnExceptionAspect
    Public Overrides Sub OnException(ByVal args As MethodExecutionArgs)
        AutoLogExceptionEventSource.Log.LogException(args.Exception.GetType().Name, args.Exception.Message, args.Exception.StackTrace)
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue
    End Sub
End Class

<EventSource(Name:=EventSourceNames.AutoLogException)>
Public NotInheritable Class AutoLogExceptionEventSource
    Inherits EventSource
    Public Class Tasks
        Public Const MethodExecution As EventTask = CType(1, EventTask)
    End Class
    Private Const ExceptionLog As Integer = EventIdBases.AutoLogException + 1
    Private Const MethodExecution As Integer = CType(1, EventTask)
    Private Shared ReadOnly Instance As Lazy(Of AutoLogExceptionEventSource) = New Lazy(Of AutoLogExceptionEventSource)(Function() New AutoLogExceptionEventSource())
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Log As AutoLogExceptionEventSource
        Get
            Return Instance.Value
        End Get
    End Property
    <[Event](ExceptionLog, Level:=EventLevel.Error, Task:=MethodExecution, Opcode:=EventOpcode.Info)>
    Public Sub LogException(exceptionType As String, message As String, stackTrace As String)
        If (IsEnabled()) Then
            WriteEvent(ExceptionLog, exceptionType, message, stackTrace)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I also have a `RollingLogFileTraceListener` **TraceListener** derived from `FileLogTraceListener`, with a few cusatom settings in the ctor. Now I have no clue how to couple this listener up to my `EventSource` class. I don't want to fill my Windows event log with large exception tack traces. How do I use this `RollingLogFileTraceListener` with my `AutoLogExceptionEventSource`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `AutoLogExceptionAspect` you need to use a custom [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of EventSource. You can then configure the listeners associated with this TraceSource in the config file or directly in the code. You can find some examples on MSDN - [How to: Create and Initialize Trace Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228984(v=vs.110).aspx)